# Python pandas nlargest() not working properly with keep = 'all'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I try to use the function below

```
top3 = df1.nlargest(3, 'perChange', keep='all')
```

Even if keep = 'all', the output is

```
92     3.828120
255   -0.673854
256   -0.673854
Name: perChange, dtype: float64
```

However, the sorted array is

```
92      3.828120
255    -0.673854
256    -0.673854
304    -1.906793
340    -2.643661
355    -3.421462
359    -3.549768
```

What I want is

```
92      3.828120
255    -0.673854
256    -0.673854
304    -1.906793
```

How can I solve the problem?

Edit:
For the people who interest to solve it, here is the example code which show the problem.

```
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'value': [3.828120, -0.673854, -0.673854, -1.906793, -2.643661]}
  
# Create DataFrame
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
test_df = test_df.nlargest(3, 'value', keep='all')
# Print the output.
print(test_df['value'])
```

Comment: So.... `nlargest(4....)` or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Chrispresso, I am trying to find the top3 result, but I want it to not drop duplicates. So, for example, if there are some rows having the same value on Rank 2, I can show it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the sample data. So, what's the problem? It's returning 3 items but you want 4?

Comment: Hi richardec, I should say I want to find the top 3 values. In this case, it is  3.828120,-0.673854, -1.906793. However, there are two rows are -0.673854. According to the doc of nlargest(), it should keep the duplicates if keep = 'all', but it is not in this case.

Comment: @Manlai keep=all should take into account unique values per the docs

Comment: see the last example (with `keep='all'`) "The n largest elements where n=3 with all duplicates kept. Note that the returned Series has five elements due to the three duplicates." (or maybe i'm just not understanding it very well)

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug for nlargest().

I write a function that does the job I want.
I sorted the df and use the function below to find the index.

```
def findnlargestI(df,n,col):
    lastValue = 0
    lastRank = 0
    for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
            currentValue = df[col].iloc[i]
            if currentValue != lastValue:
                rank = lastRank + 1
                lastRank = rank
                lastValue = currentValue
            
            if rank > n:
                return i 
top3= df1.iloc[0:findnlargestI(df1,3,'perChange'),:]
```